# find and replace line sed older version

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i'm trying to find and replace a port number in a server file (because all of my collaborators use the same server), so we need different ports... i was trying to use sed like this: `sed -i -e '/var port./var port = 3000;/' server.js` to change the port from 5000 to 3000. the acutal line of code i'm trying to replace is `var port = 5000;` in the file server.js when i try to do this on our rhel server (which i do not have root access to) i get this message `sed: -e expression #1, char 14: expected newer version of sed`

am i just not using the correct regex? or is the server making it inconvenient?

Comment: Take out `-i -e` fro your `sed`

Comment: `var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;` might be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do a find and replace, don't forget to start the command with `s`. Also, the `-e` is not necessary (but it shouldn't cause any problems). Older versions of `sed` do not support the in-place modification of files, so you should overwrite the file yourself:

```
sed 's/var port.*/var port = 3000;/' server.js > tmp && mv tmp server.js
```

It may be necessary to make the regular expression more specific but that depends on the content of the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sed command which was in this `s/pattern/replacement/modifier` format,

```
sed -i 's/var port *= *[0-9]\+/var port = 3000/' server.js
```

If you want to change the specific port number `5000` then use this,

```
sed -i 's/var port *= *5000/var port = 3000/' server.js
```